# Regex issue in Python printing entire URL

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, extract

I am trying to pull all the urls that contain "https://play.google.com/store/" and print the entire string. When I run my current code, it only prints "https://play.google.com/store/" but I am looking for the entire URL. Can someone point me in the right direction? Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re



URL = "https://www.pocketgamer.com/android/best-tycoon-games-android/?page=3"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

links = []
for link in soup.findAll("a", target="_blank"):
    links.append(link.get('href'))

x = re.findall("https://play.google.com/store/", str(links))
print(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.findall` just returns the part of the text that matches the regex, so all you are getting is the `https://play.google.com/store/` that is in the regex. You could modify the regex, but given what you are searching is a list of links, it's easier to just check if they start with `https://play.google.com/store/`. For example:

```py
x = [link for link in links if link.startswith('https://play.google.com/store/')]
```

Output (for your query):

```
[
 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.auxbrain.egginc',
 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.kairosoft.android.gamedev3en',
 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pixodust.games.idle.museum.tycoon.empire.art.history',
 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.AdrianZarzycki.idle.incremental.car.industry.tycoon',
 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.veloxia.spacecolonyidle',
 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uplayonline.esportslifetycoon',
 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.codigames.hotel.empire.tycoon.idle.game',
 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mafgames.idle.cat.neko.manager.tycoon',
 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.atari.mobile.rctempire',
 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pixodust.games.rocket.star.inc.idle.space.factory.tycoon',
 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idlezoo.game',
 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fluffyfairygames.idleminertycoon',
 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.boomdrag.devtycoon2',
 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.TomJarStudio.GamingShop2D',
 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.roasterygames.smartphonetycoon2'
]
```

Comment: @user18871432 no worries - I'm glad I could help.